# Should questions about SQL query performance be migrated to codereview?

Tags: support, migration

There are many questions on SO regarding the *performance* of OP's SQL query, often with titles ending with "too slow" or "too long".

These queries return the right results, so the code "works", but often the approach is terrible and the fix is to basically rewrite the query from scratch.

Technically these would seem like candidates for migration to codereview, but due to the often extensive rework (way beyond "style" or "tweaks") they could be considered as "asking for code" with the OP's best effort posted in the question.

Should such questions be flagged for migration?
If so, should it depend on the amount of rework, or does "working code" alone qualify it for migration?

Comment: The question is, are they off-topic for Stack Overflow? If not, they should not be migrated anywhere.

Comment: @Cody Yes, that is the question. If the code "works", are they off-topic?

Answer (score 4):

Many database performance problems have absolutely nothing to do with the code. If it's not a code problem, or it's a complex issue, why not migrate them to [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead? Unless they're asking specifically about the code, I'm not sure why it would be more on-topic at code review.

Comment: This man knows what he's talking about.

Comment: Aw shucks, thanks @Nick! :-)